# How to extract information from array of Input element in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, jquery

I  trying to use contact form using J Query ,PHP AJAX but here in the below code the form information is gathered and send it to the server using for LOOP and Array of inouts of ofrm is created . i am new to this kind of coding please help me to extract this value in PHP so that i can use this element to add in to my database or send mail contain form inputs .

```
function signUpClick(){
var form = $("#form_main")[0];
var objData = {};

for(var i=0;i<form.length;i++){
    var input = form[i];
    objData[input.name] = "";
    if(input.className == "writable")
        objData[input.name] = input.value;
}

$("#loader").show();
$("#error_message").hide();

//send contact form using ajax
$.ajax({
      url: "contact.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data:objData,
      success: function(response){
         $("#loader").hide();
         if(response == "__ok__")
            showSentMessage();
         else
            showErrorMessage(response);
      },
      error:function(){
        $("#loader").hide();
        showErrorMessage("Can't get the contact form");
      }
});
```

}

Comment: It looks like it should work. What is the problem?

Comment: i have no issue with script but i dont know how to use this objData in PHP to get form input data

Comment: Take a look at `$_POST` in PHP.

Comment: @Radu $Name=$_POST['fullname'];  suppose my form have <input type="text" name="fullname" alt="FULL NAME" value="FULL NAME">  will the above mentione PHP work?

Comment: It should. Try it out. Better yet, try `var_dump($_POST)` to see exactly what `$_POST` contains.

Comment: @Radu I got Result as below when i used echo var_dump($_POST);                Result :                                                         array(1) { ["fullname"]=> string(4) "pani" }    what next

Comment: Well... Is that not what you're looking for? This confirms that indeed `$_POST['fullname']` contains "pani". This is your value. Do whatever you need to do with it in PHP...

Comment: Thanks for your answers ,it took me several hours but you made it in  few mins ..great work thank you

Comment: @Radu what's the use of var_dump($_POST) when it's ajax call?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, you can see what `var_dump()` outputs with tools like Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side you can manage the information as an array:

`$objData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

$objData will be the PHP array equivalent to the $objData on Javascript